# How to add java application logs to systems log

Tags: java, log4j

I tried in this way but produce the following Error:-

```
log4j:ERROR Precision option (0) isn't a positive integer.
```

---

```
public class log4jExample {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SyslogAppender syslogAppender = new SyslogAppender();
            syslogAppender.setName("SYSLOG");
            syslogAppender.setSyslogHost("localhost");
            syslogAppender.setFacility("Local3");
            syslogAppender.setHeader(true);
            PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n");
            syslogAppender.setLayout(layout);
            Category category = Category.getInstance(log4jExample.class.getName());//logger.getParent();
            Throwable thrwo = new Throwable();
            LoggingEvent event = new LoggingEvent("log4jExample.class", category, 1000, Priority.DEBUG, new Object(), thrwo);
            syslogAppender.append(event);
            logger.debug("LOG");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exc " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Property file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, SYSLOG log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender 
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.SyslogHost=localhost log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Facility=Local3 
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Header=true 
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=java %d{ISO8601} %p %t %c{0}.%M - %m%n
```

Comment: What version of Log4j? I'm struggling to reproduce this with v1.2.14, but then again I'm on Windows and I've slightly edited your code to use a `ConsoleAppender`.

Comment: I found a Linux machine and tested with v1.2.17. I cannot reproduce your error, I get a warning about no appenders being found. Do you have a Log4j config file on your classpath somewhere? If so, please add it to your question.

Comment: log4j.rootLogger=INFO, SYSLOG

log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.SyslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Facility=Local3
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Header=true
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=java %d{ISO8601} %p %t %c{0}.%M - %m%n

Comment: Please use the edit button and add that to your question, correctly formatted please.

Comment: @Vishal, In log4j2, what is `log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Header=true` equivalent to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It pretty much tells you what is wrong:

```
Precision option (0) isn't a positive integer.
```

As you can read in the [`PatternLayout` documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html), `c` has a precision specifier which you have set to `0` with `%c{0}`. `0` is not a positive integer. Change it to a number >=1